# Frequency table by group in data.table (R)

Tags: r, data.table

I want to get for each group the frequencies of the values of a factor/categorial variable.

The following does not work:

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(fac=c("l1","l1","l2"),grp=c("A","B","B"))
dt[,fac:=as.factor(fac)]
dt[,list( table(fac) ),by=grp]
```

The error message is:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , list(table(fac)), by = grp) : 
  All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. If you are trying something like j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then use := by group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge afterwards.
```

Is there an easy way to accomblish this task? Thanks.

Comment: `dt[,as.list(table(fac)),by=grp]` maybe

Comment: Oh wow. That's it! Thank you :)

Comment: Or `with(dt, table(grp, fac))`...

Answer (score 4):

We can use `dcast` and bypass the second and third line of OP's code.

```
dcast(dt, grp~fac, length)
#   grp l1 l2
#1:   A  1  0
#2:   B  1  1
```

Comment: for dcast function, load firstly  data.table library:   require("data.table")

Comment: @maycca You are right.  As the OP's post showed the loading of library, I didn't show it